# Image detection in AR.js

Tags: ar.js

Can I get the result of detecting a picture to go to the next page in AR.js, for example. Since I saw that it is sending object detection messages to the console, but I cannot use the detection result in the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to AR.js documentation, the 'markerFound' is 'Fired when a marker in Marker Based, or a picture in Image Tracking, has been found'.

So if this is how you define an image to track:

```
<a-nft type="nft" imageMarkerName   ...
```

To add listener:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent(imageMarkerName, {
      init: function () {
                   var marker = this.el;
                   
                   marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function() {
                        // The image is found.
                   });
     });
```